# ERROR 000210: Cannot create output in_memory\SLR_Union.shp and ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, error-000210, error-000354

I'm receiving the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\tst_root\GIS_WORKSPACE\sprice\PatchSize_SSG_Methods_Rework\SSG\Python\SSG_Analysis_Part1_BlockListClip.py", line 169, in <module>
    arcpy.Union_analysis(unionInputs, r'in_memory\SLR_Union', "ALL")
  File "E:\sw_nt\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 851, in Union
    raise e
  File "E:\sw_nt\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 848, in Union
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Union_analysis(*gp_fixargs((in_features, out_feature_class, join_attributes, cluster_tolerance, gaps), True)))
  File "E:\sw_nt\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 520, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output in_memory\SLR_Union.shp
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (Union).
```

This is the section of code where the error is coming from:

```
# run Union on SLR Clip outputs and Dissolve
AddMsg("Running Union on SLR Clip outputs")
unionInputs = [unionInput1, unionInput2, unionInput3]
arcpy.Union_analysis(unionInputs, r'in_memory\SLR_Union', "ALL")
AddMsg("Dissolving Union output")
slr = arcpy.Dissolve_management(r'in_memory\SLR_Union', os.path.join(workingGDB,"SLR_LU"))
```

I don't understand why I'm getting these errors. Further back in the script I've been writing feature classes to in_memory with no troubles. If I change the output for the Union_analysis to the working gdb, it works, but then the same errors are thrown again when the script reaches the Dissolve step. I'm stumped as to figuring out what it is in the output name that's considered an invalid character.
I don't need these layers after the script is complete, so I'd like to write them to in_memory. I might have to write them to the working gdb, though, and just delete them at the end of the script.

Comment: The memory workspaces, i.e., "memory" and "in-memory", are like geodatabases and not folders.  You cannot put a shape file into a memory workspace, it has to be a feature class, so drop the .shp file extension.

Comment: That's something I meant to mention as well. In the script I didn't include the .shp file extension, but the tool seems to be automatically adding it. I can see how the file extension would cause the error, but I'm not sure how it's even getting there.

Comment: Try using the newer `memory` workspace, it might be the Union tool isn't liking the old `in_memory` workspace.  I am assuming you are using ArcGIS Pro and not ArcGIS Desktop/ArcMap.